# Unable to share a SharePoint Team Site with external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, office-365-groups, external-sharing

I have created a new team site inside sharepoint online. Then i defined the site to be Public + to allow external sharing as follow:-

[image]
[image]

But when i wanted to share the site with existing external user (who have access to a classic team), i got this error message "could not add **** as member", as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please?

Final note. note sure if it is related to my problem. But when i access the group (which got created automatically after creating the above team site), from the office 365 admin site, i got a message that i can not modify the group's properties due to permission (although i am sign-in as the office 365 admin):-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is by default that external users cannot be added as a member through the team site page.

You can go to Microsoft 365 admin center and select your group and then directly add a member. Then go back to your team site and refresh the page, new member will appear.

[image]

Also you can go to Outlook to add the member.

[image]

Comment: OK it worked for me from "Office 365 admin center" >> "Group", as you mentioned. where i was able to add external member. but in this case, we will be facing these 2 limitations. 1) the user who will be adding external user, need to be office 365 admin to be able to access the Group, so the team site owner will not be able to add external user unless his have office 365 admin permission. 2) second limitation , seems when adding users from the group itself, there is not any option to send an invitation email.. so is there any workaround to these limitations?

Comment: this solution is still the accepted answer. Note, you'll need to be a Site Owner. Then, add user on outlook.office365.com, then confirm (or add again) user directly to the SP site. at that point, you can change permission to be read-only, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the site choose "Other Options" (not Team Site) and then "Document Center". This will allow sharing outside the group constraint.

Answer (score -1):

In the Admin center have you set your site collection to Allow Sharing?

[image]

That can be done on Admin Center > Site Collection > select your site collection > click on Sharing

Comment: i have already set this to "New & Existing external users" as shown in my question...